# Optim: non-finite finite-difference value in L-BFGS-B

Tags: r, nonlinear-optimization

I'm trying to maximize a likelihood with R's 'optim.' I get the error "non-finite finite-difference value."

I'm using L-BFGS-B because I have to constrain the 11th parameter (Bernoulli "p") to be 0<=p<=1.  Since I need this constraint, I can't use a nongradient method like "Nelder-Mead." Any thoughts on how I can fix this?  It worked fine with simulated data!

Note that I'm using a floor function in here because discrete values are needed for the "Trials" parameters (params 1 through 10).

```
library(rmutil)
Nhat<-c(14335,15891,2700,1218,2213,10985,4985,8738,13878)
sdNhat<-
sqrt(c(26915344,6574096,175561,51529,71824,12166144,145924,2808976,3319684))
C<-c(313,410,38,30,69,175,132,193,240)
LL1<-vector()
LL2<-vector()
NLL<-function(data,par){
for (i in 1:length(Nhat)){
LL1[i]<-dnorm(Nhat[i],par[i],sdNhat[i],log=TRUE)
LL2[i]<-dbetabinom(C[i],floor(par[i]),par[length(Nhat)+1],par[length(Nhat)+2],log=TRUE)
}
-1*(sum(LL1)+sum(LL2))
}
out<-optim(par=c(floor(Nhat*runif(length(Nhat),0.9,1.1)),0.02,3),
       fn=NLL,data=list(Nhat=Nhat,sdNhat=sdNhat,C=C),
       method='L-BFGS-B',
       lower=c(rep(min(Nhat),length(Nhat)),0.0001,1),
       upper=c(rep(min(Nhat),length(Nhat)),0.9999,2))
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting an error, because the boundaries you are setting for the parameters 1 to 9 are identical. Thus, you have to adjust `upper=c(rep(min(Nhat),length(Nhat)),0.9999,2))` (or `lower`) to be an interval.

You said that only the 10th (you actually wrote 11th, but I guess that's a typo) has to be bounded between 0 and 1, so this would work:

```
set.seed(1)
out<-optim(par=c(floor(Nhat*runif(length(Nhat),0.9,1.1)),0.02,3),
           fn=NLL,data=list(Nhat=Nhat,sdNhat=sdNhat,C=C),
           method='L-BFGS-B',
           lower=c(rep(-Inf,length(Nhat)),0,-Inf),
           upper=c(rep(Inf,length(Nhat)),1,Inf))
out
# $par
# [1] 13660.61522882 15482.96819195  2730.66273051  1310.04511624  2077.45269032 11857.94955470
# [7]  5417.09464008  9016.57472573 14234.22972586     0.02165253   826.21691430
# 
# $value
# [1] 116.2657
```