# Non-finite finite difference error when using optim with L-BFGS-B method in R

Tags: r, optimization

I'm trying to obtain confidence intervals for estimates of five parameters (1 pi, a proportion with bounds between 0 and 1, 4 betas which are exponential rates of decline) using my log likelihood function. My data consists of time intervals after vaccination, immune statuses classified as ones and zeros as well as the past vaccination history and ownership status of individual dogs. My data is as below

```
data4mle <- 
  structure(
    list(
      Interval_18 = c(35, 123, 13, 140, 8, 115, 16, 
                      131, 132, 8, 13, 146, 44, 15, 138, 3, 143, 149, 12, 153, 17, 
                      154, 14, 8, 123, 16, 17, 154, 8, 135, 10, 133, 18, 8, 123, 10, 
                      133, 16, 163, 10, 150, 10, 3, 8, 8, 139, 22, 9, 122, 1, 130, 
                      16, 140, 16, 140, 20, 142, 42, 122, 16, 8, 126, 8, 8, 139, 20, 
                      122, 14, 8, 122, 146, 6, 20, 9, 6, 13, 13, 115, 12, 131, 12, 
                      12, 23, 116, 6, 102, 13, 137, 6, 107, 12, 14, 115, 18, 123, 155, 
                      158, 163, 35, 155, 16, 163, 16, 140, 44, 128, 9, 21, 36, 46, 
                      153, 27, 147, 47, 131, 8, 146, 12, 17, 9, 16, 155, 9, 10, 148, 
                      32, 148, 25, 15, 138, 46, 158, 121, 8, 131, 8, 8, 118, 31, 154, 
                      32, 144, 15, 8, 16, 8, 101, 15, 144, 12, 20, 10, 15, 142, 13, 
                      69, 28, 168, 15, 12, 24, 13, 142, 12, 115, 13, 131, 166, 13, 
                      118, 12, 32, 6, 36, 164, 16, 135, 20, 46, 19, 137, 11, 150, 6, 
                      107, 10, 148, 13, 118, 19, 164, 10, 16, 127, 19, 161, 156, 14, 
                      16, 145, 1, 143, 16, 5, 144, 158, 33, 19, 6, 6, 115, 16, 138, 
                      32, 13, 18, 13, 11, 158, 10, 151, 16, 16, 69, 17, 166, 26, 158, 
                      11, 11, 26, 16, 173, 16, 32, 155, 12, 16, 149, 16, 149, 16, 163, 
                      153, 57, 13, 128, 12, 113, 19, 144, 21, 35, 30, 30, 157, 108, 
                      14, 16, 33, 23, 149, 14, 14, 8, 18, 164, 115, 19, 11, 151, 19, 
                      144, 21, 13, 142, 54, 150, 16, 163, 22, 13, 11, 155, 155, 16, 
                      150, 16, 16, 57, 19, 17, 135, 12, 11, 12, 145, 11, 11, 170, 18, 
                      164, 10, 16, 12, 11, 155, 27, 11, 24, 16, 135, 47, 12, 17, 149, 
                      11, 12, 18, 137, 10, 131, 11, 151, 12, 131, 11, 158, 57, 12, 
                      5, 27, 23, 16, 24, 149, 29, 150, 12, 16, 157, 16, 10, 152, 16, 
                      10, 149, 23, 11, 30, 16, 141, 27, 147, 11, 151, 16, 157, 71, 
                      172, 32, 151, 11, 151, 10, 131, 27, 147, 22, 23, 20, 139, 10, 
                      131, 12, 145, 16, 149, 10, 135, 145, 13, 135, 16, 149, 30, 150, 
                      16, 163, 141, 51, 131, 16, 25, 16, 140, 32, 144, 41, 129, 14, 
                      8, 123, 16, 149, 101, 14, 94, 10, 139, 8, 10, 130, 96, 8, 24, 
                      144, 8, 8, 129, 20, 129, 10, 131, 8, 9, 131, 8, 127, 10, 130, 
                      22, 142, 8, 127, 13, 127, 10, 131, 10, 131, 24, 166, 8, 129, 
                      10, 131, 9, 20, 146, 8, 127, 10, 134, 10, 131, 10, 132, 10, 15, 
                      15, 20, 142, 8, 127, 11, 9, 11, 170, 10, 131, 20, 129, 144, 10, 
                      130, 10, 130, 8, 127, 10, 131, 8, 8, 130, 10, 14, 128, 10, 148, 
                      13, 127, 10, 131, 8, 127, 9, 125, 14, 129, 13, 13, 129, 27, 147, 
                      9, 131, 8, 130, 14, 128, 1, 105, 1, 105, 9, 13, 137, 8, 10, 131, 
                      17, 148, 13, 127, 8, 10, 8, 10, 10, 122, 116, 14, 128, 14, 128, 
                      11, 159, 10, 131, 20, 122), 
      Immune_status = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
                        0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
                        1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
                        1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
                        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
                        0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                        0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
                        1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
                        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
                        1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
                        1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                        0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
                        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
                        1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
                        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
                        0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                        1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
                        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
                        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                        1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
                        0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
                        1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
                        0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                        1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
                        1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
                        1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                        0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1), 
      Owned = c("No", "No", "No", 
                "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", 
                "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", 
                "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", 
                "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", 
                "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", 
                "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", 
                "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", 
                "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", 
                "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", 
                "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", 
                "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", 
                "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", 
                "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", 
                "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", 
                "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", 
                "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", 
                "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", 
                "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", 
                "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", 
                "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", 
                "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                "No", "No"), 
      Not_vacc_not_revacc_before_R3 = c("No", "No", "No", 
                                        "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                                        "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", 
                                        "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", 
                                        "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", 
                                        "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                                        "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", 
                                        "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", 
                                        "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", 
                                        "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                                        "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", 
                                        "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", 
                                        "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                                        "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", 
                                        "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", 
                                        "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", 
                                        "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", 
                                        "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", 
                                        "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                                        "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", 
                                        "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", 
                                        "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                                        "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                                        "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", 
                                        "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                                        "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", 
                                        "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", 
                                        "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                                        "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", 
                                        "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", 
                                        "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", 
                                        "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", 
                                        "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", 
                                        "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", 
                                        "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", 
                                        "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", 
                                        "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", 
                                        "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", 
                                        "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", 
                                        "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                                        "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                                        "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", 
                                        "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                                        "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                                        "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
                                        "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                                        "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                                        "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", 
                                        "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                                        "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", 
                                        "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
                                        "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", 
                                        "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", 
                                        "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", 
                                        "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes")), 
    row.names = c(NA,-542L), 
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And my log-likelihood function

```
nll.18.4betas <- function(v) {
  #function(pi,beta) {
  pi <- v[1]; beta_o_v <- v[2]; beta_o_nv <- v[3]; beta_no_v <- v[4]; beta_no_nv <- v[5]
  
  data <- data4mle %>% 
    filter(Interval_18 > 0 & Interval_18 <= 180 & !is.na(Immune_status))
  
  #Owned, vaccinated/revaccinated
  xi_o_v <- data %>% 
    filter(Owned == "Yes" & Not_vacc_not_revacc_before_R3 == "Yes") %>% 
    .$Immune_status
  ti_o_v <- data %>% 
    filter(Owned == "Yes" & Not_vacc_not_revacc_before_R3 == "Yes") %>% 
    .$Interval_18
  
  #Owned, not vaccinated/revaccinated
  xi_o_nv <- data %>% 
    filter(Owned == "Yes" & Not_vacc_not_revacc_before_R3 == "No") %>% 
    .$Immune_status
  ti_o_nv <- data %>% 
    filter(Owned == "Yes" & Not_vacc_not_revacc_before_R3 == "No") %>% 
    .$Interval_18
  
  #Not owned, vaccinated/revaccinated
  xi_no_v <- data %>% 
    filter(Owned == "No" & Not_vacc_not_revacc_before_R3 == "Yes") %>% 
    .$Immune_status
  ti_no_v <- data %>% 
    filter(Owned == "No" & Not_vacc_not_revacc_before_R3 == "Yes") %>% 
    .$Interval_18
  
  ##Not owned, not vaccinated/revaccinated
  xi_no_nv <- data %>% 
    filter(Owned == "No" & Not_vacc_not_revacc_before_R3 == "No") %>% 
    .$Immune_status
  ti_no_nv <- data %>% 
    filter(Owned == "No" & Not_vacc_not_revacc_before_R3 == "No") %>% 
    .$Interval_18
  
  #calculate neg log likelihood
  #Owned, vaccinated/revaccinated
  -sum(xi_o_v*(log(pi)-beta_o_v*ti_o_v) + (1-xi_o_v)*log(1 - (pi*exp(-beta_o_v*ti_o_v)))) + 
    #Owned, not vaccinated/revaccinated
    -sum(xi_o_nv*(log(pi)-beta_o_nv*ti_o_nv) + (1-xi_o_nv)*log(1 - (pi*exp(-beta_o_nv*ti_o_nv)))) + 
    #Not owned, vaccinated/revaccinated
    -sum(xi_no_v*(log(pi)-beta_no_v*ti_no_v) + (1-xi_no_v)*log(1 - (pi*exp(-beta_no_v*ti_no_v)))) +
    #Not owned, not vaccinated/revaccinated
    -sum(xi_no_nv*(log(pi)-beta_no_nv*ti_no_nv) + (1-xi_no_nv)*log(1 - (pi*exp(-beta_no_nv*ti_no_nv))))
  
}

trial <- optim(fn = nll.18.4betas, par = c(0.1,  0.003,0.003,0.003, 0.003), 
               lower = c(0.1, rep(1e-3, 4)),
               upper = c(0.99,rep(1e-1, 4)), 
               method = "L-BFGS-B", hessian = T)
```

I keep getting the non-finite finite difference error when trying to estimate a hessian, even though the optimisation method itself runs fine and generates estimates of the five parameters (i.e. when `hessian = FALSE`). I need to use L-BFGS-B, because the first parameter pi is a proportion that necessarily has to be bound between 0 and 1.

I looked at suggestions in this question ([non-finite finite-difference value, many data become inf and NA after exponential](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28185387/non-finite-finite-difference-value-many-data-become-inf-and-na-after-exponentia/28185475)), but from what I understand, I would need to use the Nelder-Mead method to use the numDeriv package.

Similarly, the response to this question ([Optim: non-finite finite-difference value in L-BFGS-B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45338227/optim-non-finite-finite-difference-value-in-l-bfgs-b)) doesn't seem to apply, and I'm not sure if what's discussed here relates directly to my issue ([optim in r :non finite finite difference error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361821/optim-in-r-non-finite-finite-difference-error)).

I'm not sure what's happening here, especially because when I run the optimisation for a nested model with six parameters (2 pis and 4 betas), 'optim' is able to generate a hessian and thus I can compute confidence intervals.

Not sure if this provides enough information for someone to help, but would appreciate any advice.
Thanks!

Comment: I tried to run your code, but I get many errors. I suspect something is missing.

Comment: Sorry about that @PaulSmith, I've edited my post to dput the whole data. Hope that works now

Answer (score 0):

The following code seems to produce a valid solution, according to your constraints:

```
set.seed(100)
trial <- optim(fn = nll.18.4betas, 
               par = runif(5), 
               method = "Nelder-Mead", hessian = T,
               control=list(maxit=5000))

# RESULT

$par
[1] 0.999362670 0.005248378 0.011744520 0.002088864 0.007242104

$value
[1] 258.8472

$counts
function gradient 
    1034       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL

$hessian
            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]      [,4]       [,5]
[1,]    9811.427  -4834.189  -9284.515 -106446.3  -43436.32
[2,]   -4834.189 677710.202      0.000       0.0       0.00
[3,]   -9284.515      0.000 354806.186       0.0       0.00
[4,] -106446.252      0.000      0.000 9402389.7       0.00
[5,]  -43436.320      0.000      0.000       0.0 1259387.74
```